# C++ Extend Windows WRL component class not working

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, windows-runtime, wrl

I have a class `ClassA` implement interface `IFooBar` like below

```
class ClassA : public Microsoft::WRL::RuntimeClass<IFooBar>
{
public:
    virtual HRESULT RuntimeClassInitialize(ParamsForClassA);
}
```

Now I want to write a `ClassB` inherent `ClassA` and override it's `RuntimeClassInitialize` function like below:

```
class ClassB : public ClassA
{
public:
    HRESULT RuntimeClassInitialize(ParamsForClassB)
    {
        // implementation goes here
    }
}
```

And I create a pointer to `ClassB` object like this:

```
ComPtr<ClassB> ptr;
HRESULT hr = MakeAndInitialize<ClassB>(&ptr, ParamsForClassB);
```

But this actually goes to `ClassA`'s `RuntimeClassInitialize` constructor. The `ClassB`'s `RuntimeClassInitialize` code path is never hit.

I am wondering if this is the correct way of extending class in WRL? Where am I doing wrong in the code?

Comment: if the args are different then you will have 2 member functions called RuntimeClassInitialize. The one from B will not override the one from A

Comment: @cppguy `ClassA` and `ClassB` takes different numbers of parguments. But I am passing the right args to the ClassB's `MakeAndInitialize` function. Magically it goes to class A as a result...

Comment: @AllanJiang Do you still see this problem? It's fine on my machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the overridden methods to have the same **signature** on both classes.

this

```
HRESULT RuntimeClassInitialize(ParamsForClassA);
```

Can't be overridden by this

```
HRESULT RuntimeClassInitialize(ParamsForClassB);
```

Because they take different arguments.
It's an **overload**, not an **override**.
(And such overloads cause [Name Hiding](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/c-cplusplus/c-name-hiding/))

You can find info on signatures [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_signature#Signature) or [here](http://www.cs.unm.edu/~storm/C++/ProgrammingTerms/FunctionSignatures.html).